# Windows 10 - Network Sign-in and cached credentials

Tags: windows, active-directory, vpn

I'm managing remote laptops connected to our self-hosted domain (Samba 4, in case it's importante, but I don't think so).

Windows PCs have a IKEv2 VPN configured, so from the login screen they can login using the Network Sign-in button. This works great, until for some reason we reset the password.

If the password is reset, Network Sign-in will connect to the VPN with the *new* password, but Windows 10 will fail to log-in as it has the old password cached.

The workaround, so far, is to login with the old password, and then execute something using `runas` to cache the updated password.

Is there a way for Network Sign-In to update the cached password when it properly connects to the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for Network Sign-In to update the cached password

No. This is an education issue. Users should change their password when they are connected, then CTRL-ATL-DELETE and lock/unlock the computer. Done.